# Invalid SharePoint App package spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I'm trying to deploy my spfx app to the app catalog and after I upload it it appears in the app catalog in the 'Unavailable Apps' view with the Error message :

> Invalid SharePoint App package. Error: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideFramework.SPClientSideComponentMetadata'
>   to type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideComponentMetadata

I've deployed the app many times previously and it worked. What does this message mean?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more details on what the solution package actually contains and what kind of tenant you are using? - Just to understand how to create repro and solve the issue. Thx.

There should not be any changes on the normal tenants in the context of client-side web parts.

Thx for the additional details advance, will help us to narrow down the issue.

---

Apparently we should have already fixed this in the SPO side, based on the discussion in following entry at MS Tech Community - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Invalid-Package-Sharepoint-Framework-Extensions/m-p/75585#M2576.

Comment: Its a production tenant on first release. Its an spfx webapart,. Was trying to set up external libraries, but it doid not work, so I backed off the external library changes and then hit this issue. not sure if its related.

Comment: Hey @russellg - are you working now?

Comment: yes, rolled back to previous version and its fine, rganks for follow up